# Let $X$ be a Banach space. $P∈B(X)$ satisfies $P^2=P$. Prove that $X=\ker P⊕P(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $P∈B(X)$ satisfies $P^2=P$. How to prove that $X=\ker P⊕P(X)$ ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: what mean $B(X)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$x-P(x)\in \ker(P)$$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try.